# Jenkins failed to build SpringBoot Project (could not find the class org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor)

Tags: java, spring, jenkins

When i used Jenkins to build a springboot(1.4.0 version) project, a problem encoutered, which is about not being able to find the class org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor. The building error is as follow:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/asm/ClassVisitor
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.findMainMethod(Repackager.java:310)
>       at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo$LoggingRepackager.findMainMethod(RepackageMojo.java:372)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.buildManifest(Repackager.java:284)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:207)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.Repackager.repackage(Repackager.java:152)
>       at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo.repackage(RepackageMojo.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo.execute(RepackageMojo.java:193)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>       ... 32 more
>   **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:** org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)

However, the class org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor existed in the spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar. It seemed tha maven was unable to locate the required class when building the project. Additionally, i have to make it clear that i didn't include spring-asm-xxx.jar in my springboot project, so there was no chance of existing a jar conflict. And, what is very strange to me is, that i built the same springboot project successfully in IDEA.

I've no idea why this would happen. What possible reasons do you think are to cause this problem? Looking forward to your reply! Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can't really help unless you have an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What Jenkins config are you using? What does your pom say? What's the command that is run?

Comment: Class not found is most commonly caused by bad POM file, could you provide it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. Luckily I've solved the problem by integrating two local maven repositories. Previously, about a month ago, I once built successfully a springboot project in Jenkins. And for last springboot project which I failed to build in Jenkins, I used another local maven repository, which encountered the problem that I mentioned above. Today I tried integrating the two maven repositories to if it would work, and very luckily it worked and the springboot project was built successfully. In spite of that, I'm still confused about what went wrong with the problematic repository.